# Getting a list of all Gradle tasks from build script

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

So I'm trying to write a list of all gradle tasks to a file. I of course could use the `tasks` command for this, but I want cache it to a file every time any *other* gradle command is called. So whenever I run `./gradlew build` for example, I want the available tasks to be written to a file.

This seemed simple enough, and I wrote the below task to try it out:

```
task cacheTasks() {
    doLast {
        allprojects { p ->
            p.tasks*.each { t ->
                println(p.name + ":" + t.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I only get a sub-set of all the tasks available. When I run the `./gradlew tasks --all` command, many more are printed. It seems that none of the built-in tasks (like `build`, `clean` or `help`) are in the `tasks*` List when I loop over it, but oddly enough I *can* reference them directly:

```
tasks.build { t ->
    println("DEBUG:" + t.name)
}
```

It seems so simple, yet I've been searching in vain for a solution. I even tried looking in the gradle source code to see how the `tasks` Task works, but I couldn't find any clue as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`rootProject.getAllTasks(true)` looks like it's retrieving more tasks than `rootProject.tasks`.

Comment: I do believe this is the correct answer. `rootProject.getAllTasks(true)` returns a map from project instances to task instances and it seems to return all tasks, including tasks like `build` which have been injected by plugins like `java` or `groovy`.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt there is a task class in container with name `build`.

This is what I get when I debug your task:

[image: tasks]

---

I am not saying `gradle build` does not run, but it can be in other forms maybe an instance of `org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild`. (I am not very sure because the gradle source code is very hard for me to compile and run).

When using

```
tasks.build { t ->
    println("DEBUG:" + t.name)
}
```

You actually call `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer#create(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>, groovy.lang.Closure)` and create a new task named `build`.

Comment: Good point that `tasks.build` creates a new task. I forgot that would happen. However, this does not answer the question of how I can get a list of all tasks...

Comment: Normally the build task is injected into the gradle build process by applying a plugin, say the java or groovy plugin for example.